# How to search a value in Object which has values in array as well?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search, key-value

I've an object as below;

```
FOO: {
        BAR: [9,32,8,12 ],
        ZET: 4,
        BETA: [3,14,6,2],
        ALPHA: 37
    },
```

I need to search values of this object to match values with `keys`. There are tons of samples which gives `keys` with a singular value but I couldn't find any sample which also able to search in values those are in arrays.

How can I be able to search whole of those values of `FOO` object and match with `keys`?

**Note**: The aim; I'll looking for an input and if given input is `2` then expect to get the key `BETA` or if given input is `4` then `ZET`.

So basically the values will be some pre-defined unique values already.

Comment: please add the value you are looking for, the result and what you have tried.

Comment: I'll provide values depends on different input. So the aim if given input is `2` then expect to get the key `BETA` or if given input  is `4` then `ZET`...

Comment: What if a value exists both as independent and in array as well?

Comment: @MohammadUsman I've update post and there wont be any duplicate values.

Comment: Are these numbers unique in `FOO`? Can a number be in more than 1 array?

Comment: @Dmitry no. they will be unique as i've noted in post.

Comment: Do you basically want to treat the entire thing as one array of values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a simple `for...in` loop and `.concAT()` and `.includes()` methods of arrays:

```js
let obj = {
  BAR: [9,32,8,12 ],
  ZET: 4,
  BETA: [3,14,6,2],
  ALPHA: 37
};

let locator = (o, v) => {
  for (var prop in o) {
    if([].concat(o[prop]).includes(v)){
      return prop;
    }
  }
}

console.log(locator(obj, 2));
console.log(locator(obj, 4));
```

Comment: Dear @MohammadUsman thanks for solution and it has totally a very good usage with all global obj. That worked so well for my aim.

Answer (score 7):

You could get the keys, create an array of values and check with `includes`. Return the found key.

```js
function find(object, value) {
    return Object
        .keys(object)
        .find(k => [].concat(object[k]).includes(value));
}

var object = { FOO: { BAR: [9, 32, 8, 12], ZET: 4, BETA: [3, 14, 6, 2], ALPHA: 37 } };

console.log(find(object.FOO, 4));
console.log(find(object.FOO, 8));
```

Comment: This is basically where I was going with this also

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```js
// What we're searching
FOO = {
        BAR: [9,32,8,12 ],
        ZET: 4,
        BETA: [3,14,6,2],
        ALPHA: 37
    };


function findValue(findValue, obj) {
    return Object.entries(FOO)
    .filter(([key,value]) => value === findValue || Array.isArray(value) && value.includes(findValue))
    .map(([key,value])=> key);
}

function testfindValue(value, obj) {
    console.log("testfindValue: \nInput: " + value, "Result: ", findValue(value,obj));
}

testfindValue(4, FOO);
testfindValue(6, FOO);
testfindValue(32, FOO);
testfindValue(99, FOO);
```

Comment: Dear @TerryLennox your snippet works perfect but still I'll go with @MohammedUsman 's solution while I've to define which obj. should be consider in  return statement of `findValue` but Usman 's solution can work with any obj. 

So thanks for your effort.

Comment: Great,  glad to see you got a solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop though the object and search for the value to identify the key. If multiple matches are found, an array of keys that matches the result will be returned.

```js
function objSearch(key, obj) {
  const keys = [];
  for (let item in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
      if (obj[item] === key || (Array.isArray(obj[item]) && obj[item].indexOf(key) > -1)) {
        keys.push(item);
      }
    }
  }
  return keys;
}

const obj = {
  FOO: {
    BAR: [9, 32, 8, 12],
    ZET: 4,
    BETA: [3, 14, 6, 2],
    ALPHA: 37
  }
};

const res1 = objSearch(14, obj.FOO); // Exist
const res2 = objSearch(15, obj.FOO); // Does not exist
const res3 = objSearch(37, obj.FOO); // Exist

console.log(res1);
console.log(res2);
console.log(res3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet,

I am checking conditions for object values whether its array or value and applied condition as per that. I kept parent key dynamic too.

```js
var abc = {
  FOO: {
    BAR: [9, 32, 8, 12],
    ZET: 4,
    BETA: [3, 14, 6, 2],
    ALPHA: 37
  },
  DAB: {
    DBAR: [9, 32, 8, 12],
    DZET: 4,
    DBETA: [3, 14, 6, 2],
    DALPHA: 37
  },
};

function retTitle(abc, parent, k) {
  var title = '';
  $.each(abc[parent], function(x, y) {
    if ((Array.isArray(y) && y.indexOf(k) != -1) || (!Array.isArray(y) && y == k)) {
      title = x;
      return;
    }
  });
  return title;
}
var title = retTitle(abc, 'DAB', 4);
console.log(title);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `for...in` loop to iterate over keys. Then check if the value is a number and equals to what you look for. If it's not a number then it's an array - so you check that this array includes the number you are looking for.

```js
var FOO = {
        BAR: [9,32,8,12 ],
        ZET: 4,
        BETA: [3,14,6,2],
        ALPHA: 37
    };

function findKeyByValue(obj, val) {
  for (var i in FOO) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
    if (typeof FOO[i] === 'number') {
      if(FOO[i] === val) return i;
    } else {
      if(FOO[i].includes(val)) return i;
    }
  }
}

console.log(findKeyByValue(FOO, 4));
```